# Alternate way for ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working with MVC 3. On select of dropdown I have a jquery ajax method which returns a partial view.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Date/GetNextData',
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    data: { ID: dataID },
    success: function (result) {
        $('followup').html(result);
    }
});
```

Is there any alternate way to do this without using ajax?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part of AJAX don't you want to use and why? You can use UpdatePanels, but that's inefficient.

Comment: I dont want to use jquery ajax. Is there any MVC alternate for this scenario?

Comment: Use straight JavaScript AJAX (beware, you'll end up with cross browser issues!) or AJAX.NET (beware, massive page payload bloat!). Otherwise you're out of luck I'd imagine unless you fancy full page reloads.

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery AJAX? It's the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use AJAX you will have to update the entire page. You cannot just refresh a portion of your DOM. So you could subscribe to the change event of the dropdown and manually trigger the submission of the containing form. For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ItemId, Model.Items, new { id = "myDdl" })
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and then you could have a function that will submit the form when the value changes:

```
$('#myDdl').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Since you are no longer using AJAX your controller action will now have to return a full view and not a partial.